# Why is fso.copyfile method not finding the path?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm going through folders in Sharepoint and copying all of the .xlsx files to a folder on my desktop. However, there seems to be an issue finding the path which is resulting in a Error 76: Path not Found.

I've scoured this website as well as others for insight into a solution, but there hasn't been any that have worked for me.

This is my current code.

```
Dim path As String
Dim destination As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim obj_folder As Object
Dim obj_subfolder As Object
Dim file As Object

path = "\\mycompany.sharepoint.com\etc\etc"
destination = "C:\Users\adrian\Desktop\Practice\
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.filesystemobject")
Set obj_folder = fso.getfolder(path)

For Each obj_subfolder In obj_folder.subfolders
    For Each file In obj_subfolder.Files
        If InStr(1, file.Name, ".xlsx") Then
            Call fso.copyfile(file.path, destination & fso.getbasename(file) & ".xlsx")
        End If
    Next file
Next obj_subfolder
```

Things I tried:

1. I enabled the Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference.
2. I removed the & fso.getbasename(file) & ".xlsx" from the fso.copyfile
   Takeda_DigitalTrialPlatform_RFI v2.xlsx

Comment: Any particular reason you're using VBA to copy files?  There are easier ways to copy files from Sharepoint.

Comment: @fbueckert That's my instruction. There will be hundreds of folders in this location.

Comment: There are still easier ways.  I'm trying to figure out why you have to use VBA to do it; just mapping the drive would likely be quicker, and much, much easier.

Comment: @fbueckert I have the drive mapped. There will be other numerous files in that location that are not xlsx files. It would be time consuming to have to manually look for all of the files I need.

Comment: And now that you have it mapped, you have a handy dandy search you can use in explorer to find all .xlsx files.

Comment: Use the drive letter mapped to the Sharepoint folder and rewrite your VBA based on that. Ok?

Comment: @fbueckert this is just preliminary code to prepare for the real thing. I will actually be having to distinguish between different .xlsm files based upon their metadata. So some files will be relevant whereas others won't. I'm looking for help with this specifc question at this time.

Comment: Then you need to provide the full context of what it is you're trying to do.  With what you currently have, VBA isn't necessary, and is, in fact, more complicated.

Comment: @fbueckert Are you able to help with the current question which is helping me debug why the copy isn't working?

Comment: Why it's not working, I don't know; you don't provide enough information to try to debug it.  I'm pointing out that your current solution is over-complicating the problem.  You don't need a programming solution for what you are currently asking for.

Comment: @fbueckert what additional information do you need to help debug it?

Comment: it is easier to define `Dim fso As New FileSystemObject` which gives you access to all the methods and properties in the IDE. PS You think it is a good idea to post publicly personally identifiable information like your user id and the domain your company uses? If this is hospital you should be very careful to comply with all privacy rules.

Comment: @ja72 Thanks for the tip, but I did change up my user id and domain for this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and modify to your preferences

```
'*****************************************************
'* Find files in subfolders
'* Ver. 0.99
'*
Option Explicit
Const ROOTFOLDER = "X:"             'Change as desired
Const EXTENSION = "xlsx"            'Change as desired
Const FILES = "*." & EXTENSION

Dim g_FolderCount As Integer
Dim g_FileCount As Integer

Sub Test()                      'Test code. Replace with your actual code
    Dim Path As String

    g_FileCount = 0
    g_FolderCount = 0
    Path = ROOTFOLDER
    GetSubFolders Path
    Debug.Print "Number of folders: " & g_FolderCount & ". Number of files: " & g_FileCount
End Sub
'****************************************************************
'* Recursive sub to find path and files in subfolders
'*
Sub GetSubFolders(Path As String)
    Dim FSO As Object           'Late binding: Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim myFolder As Object      'Late binding: Folder
    Dim mySubFolder As Object

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(Path)
    If myFolder.SubFolders.Count <> 0 Then
        ProcessFiles Path                             'First branch (root)
        For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
            g_FolderCount = g_FolderCount + 1
            GetSubFolders mySubFolder.Path
        Next
    Else  'No more subfolders in Path, process files in current path
        ProcessFiles Path
    End If
End Sub
'*********************************************
'* Callback from GetSubFolders
'* Process files in the found folder
'*
Sub ProcessFiles(ByVal Path As String)
    Dim theFilePattern As String
    Dim theFile As String

    Path = Path & "\"
    theFilePattern = Path & FILES
    theFile = Dir(theFilePattern)
    While theFile <> ""    'Process each file here if needed
        g_FileCount = g_FileCount + 1
        Debug.Print Path & theFile
        theFile = Dir()    ' Next file if any
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`fso.GetBasenanme` argument should be a string, not a `file` object, which is likely why it's causing issues on the copy.  Since you already know the file is a `.xlsx` just use the original filename and use the `fso.BuildPath` function.

I would modify the copy line like so:
`fso.copyfile(file.path, fso.BuildPath(destination, file.name))`

Comment: I made that change, but I still receive the error in the same spot. I'm thinking it's because of the source path...I'm just not sure why. Are there any issues with using a sharepoint path as a source path in .copyfile?

Comment: It could be any number of things.  Try it manually first, then check things such as user permissions, authentication, etc.